# ipython3 --pylab loading 3960 row from csv but output trucated

Tags: python, pandas

I import a csv file with 3960 rows. It's a log of data for 100 symbols taken on a daily basis so the symbols ( column 1) repeat for each day (column 0).

Here's an example of a symbol for one day.

```
2015-08-04 02:14:05.249392,AA,0.019310361191284278,0.01935152119607817,0.0249713335081722,30.654248063382706,30.719587545370825,39.640763020966645,0.21314984420108818,29.040674658863264,13524.534781018152,89,57,99
```

I enter the pandas command:

```
df = pd.read_csv('hvanal2015.csv',names=['date','sym','20sd','10sd','5sd','hv20','hv10','hv5','d2010','d105','dabs','2010rank','105rank','absrank'])
```

and then "print out" df and I get weird output and missing data? I thought what I was doing was correct, load the data into a dataframe and just to check all ok just type df into ipython to print out the result?

Here is the result of entering df into ipython

```
date    sym      20sd      10sd       5sd  0     2015-08-04 02:14:05.249392     AA  0.019310  0.019352  0.024971   
1     2015-08-04 02:14:05.325113   AAPL  0.017051  0.013794  0.010592   
2     2015-08-04 02:14:05.415193    AIG  0.008081  0.007330  0.007621   
3     2015-08-04 02:14:05.486185   AMZN  0.023565  0.030583  0.009270   
4     2015-08-04 02:14:05.551904   APOL  0.024669  0.015697  0.018452   
5     2015-08-04 02:14:05.689820     BA  0.011363  0.011968  0.009546   
6     2015-08-04 02:14:05.776417    BAC  0.015475  0.013406  0.012332   
7     2015-08-04 02:14:05.865606    BBY  0.015891  0.007420  0.005708   
8     2015-08-04 02:14:05.946818   BIDU  0.042233  0.055172  0.075642   
9     2015-08-04 02:14:06.011993    BMY  0.013811  0.016131  0.009831   
10    2015-08-04 02:14:06.089310    BTU  0.081906  0.098044  0.086738   
11    2015-08-04 02:14:06.156129      C  0.015506  0.011763  0.006631   
12    2015-08-04 02:14:06.296579    CAT  0.016243  0.020149  0.018912   
13    2015-08-04 02:14:06.418629   CIEN  0.018688  0.017319  0.013203   
14    2015-08-04 02:14:06.484864    CLF  0.087612  0.115459  0.128460   
15    2015-08-04 02:14:06.572566  CMCSA  0.012183  0.014665  0.009780   
16    2015-08-04 02:14:06.644546    CMG  0.019171  0.023834  0.005643   
17    2015-08-04 02:14:06.716458    COH  0.013506  0.012694  0.015716   
18    2015-08-04 02:14:06.840608    CRM  0.013037  0.015606  0.011425   
19    2015-08-04 02:14:06.967105     DB  0.018022  0.015883  0.015099   
20    2015-08-04 02:14:07.043805     DE  0.009732  0.011303  0.011177   
21    2015-08-04 02:14:07.114875   EBAY  0.189311  0.009449  0.012621   
22    2015-08-04 02:14:07.233759    EEM  0.014977  0.011843  0.013190   
23    2015-08-04 02:14:07.313043    EWJ  0.011872  0.005209  0.004348   
24    2015-08-04 02:14:07.398756    EWW  0.010863  0.013477  0.009761   
25    2015-08-04 02:14:07.467548    EWZ  0.019706  0.020688  0.019828   
26    2015-08-04 02:14:07.530146      F  0.014103  0.014731  0.018003   
27    2015-08-04 02:14:07.611234     FB  0.018982  0.016290  0.015479   
28    2015-08-04 02:14:07.693674    FCX  0.046266  0.061271  0.054798   
29    2015-08-04 02:14:07.782691    FDX  0.011408  0.013163  0.013788   
...                          ...    ...       ...       ...       ...   
3930  2015-09-28 01:00:20.589634    SPY  0.013055  0.010042  0.006734   
3931  2015-09-28 01:00:20.655678    TBT  0.019665  0.023604  0.022643   
3932  2015-09-28 01:00:20.741748    TGT  0.014070  0.011213  0.009451   
3933  2015-09-28 01:00:20.813116    TLT  0.010159  0.012263  0.012021   
3934  2015-09-28 01:00:20.884421    TOL  0.017144  0.013470  0.012791   
3935  2015-09-28 01:00:20.961626   TSLA  0.018990  0.015661  0.015261   
3936  2015-09-28 01:00:21.379167   TWTR  0.022776  0.021697  0.018973   
3937  2015-09-28 01:00:21.460016    UAL  0.025244  0.027816  0.017765   
3938  2015-09-28 01:00:21.530800    UNG  0.016253  0.013991  0.011630   
3939  2015-09-28 01:00:21.611247    USO  0.035293  0.028212  0.023191   
3940  2015-09-28 01:00:21.683311      V  0.013683  0.010445  0.010751   
3941  2015-09-28 01:00:21.758811   ^VIX  0.079399  0.065535  0.078897   
3942  2015-09-28 01:00:21.835376    VLO  0.018881  0.015716  0.010171   
3943  2015-09-28 01:00:21.928583    VXX  0.067766  0.064228  0.048297   
3944  2015-09-28 01:00:22.008667    WBA  0.015618  0.016432  0.016993   
3945  2015-09-28 01:00:22.099665    WFC  0.018403  0.015706  0.013447   
3946  2015-09-28 01:00:22.172830    WFM  0.015914  0.015307  0.003510   
3947  2015-09-28 01:00:22.268512    WMT  0.013354  0.006830  0.003087   
3948  2015-09-28 01:00:22.341328      X  0.028864  0.035593  0.041663   
3949  2015-09-28 01:00:22.409256    XHB  0.014366  0.010154  0.008660   
3950  2015-09-28 01:00:22.482280    XLE  0.016997  0.016652  0.008939   
3951  2015-09-28 01:00:22.559870    XLF  0.014742  0.013247  0.011688   
3952  2015-09-28 01:00:22.634289    XLK  0.014146  0.010066  0.009843   
3953  2015-09-28 01:00:22.723142    XLU  0.012083  0.009462  0.008826   
3954  2015-09-28 01:00:22.794048    XLV  0.015060  0.012652  0.009982   
3955  2015-09-28 01:00:22.893138    XOM  0.015312  0.011989  0.008384   
3956  2015-09-28 01:00:23.981924    XOP  0.026205  0.025934  0.014844   
3957  2015-09-28 01:00:24.065460    XRT  0.155337  0.010598  0.006932   
3958  2015-09-28 01:00:24.144621   YHOO  0.018832  0.018856  0.015464   
3959  2015-09-28 01:00:24.230014    YUM  0.016179  0.014138  0.007585   

            hv20        hv10         hv5      d2010       d105          dabs  0      30.654248   30.719588   39.640763   0.213150  29.040675  13524.534781   
1      27.067031   21.897596   16.813586 -19.098641 -23.217206     21.564707   
2      12.827896   11.635388   12.098524  -9.296211   3.980406   -142.817508   
3      37.408190   48.548726   14.716225  29.781006 -69.687722   -334.000562   
4      39.161394   24.918185   29.291491 -36.370537  17.550663   -148.255167   
5      18.038308   18.999208   15.153943   5.326997 -20.239080   -479.934101   
6      24.565501   21.280620   19.575871 -13.371929  -8.010804    -40.092385   
7      25.225636   11.778962    9.061472 -53.305591 -23.070705    -56.719915   
8      67.042977   87.582752  120.078276  30.636728  37.102652     21.105140   
9      21.924209   25.607844   15.605451  16.801678 -39.059880   -332.476061   
10    130.022519  155.640574  137.691918  19.702783 -11.532119   -158.530404   
11     24.614876   18.673158   10.525944 -24.138731 -43.630613     80.749408   
12     25.784506   31.985054   30.021284  24.047577  -6.139650   -125.531261   
13     29.666339   27.493848   20.958431  -7.323084 -23.770473    224.596479   
14    139.080183  183.285382  203.923987  31.783967  11.260366    -64.572181   
15     19.339677   23.279854   15.525712  20.373537 -33.308378   -263.488440   
16     30.432227   37.835889    8.957362  24.328361 -76.325752   -413.731577   
17     21.439346   20.150395   24.948773  -6.012082  23.812823   -496.082834   
18     20.694965   24.773232   18.136937  19.706569 -26.788168   -235.935221   
19     28.609026   25.212881   23.968570 -11.870886  -4.935219    -58.425858   
20     15.449088   17.942718   17.743381  16.140953  -1.110963   -106.882885   
21    300.522219   14.999228   20.034875 -95.008945  33.572708   -135.336365   
22     23.775452   18.800884   20.938294 -20.923129  11.368668   -154.335410   
23     18.846349    8.268582    6.902262 -56.126345 -16.524235    -70.558862   
24     17.245198   21.393317   15.495197  24.053757 -27.569916   -214.617920   
25     31.282840   32.840897   31.475970   4.980550  -4.156181   -183.448238   
26     22.387271   23.384485   28.578129   4.454376  22.209787    398.605984   
27     30.132770   25.859382   24.571435 -14.181865  -4.980577    -64.880664   
28     73.444704   97.265239   86.989169  32.433292 -10.564998   -132.574546   
29     18.109567   20.896164   21.888316  15.387429   4.748012    -69.143565   
...          ...         ...         ...        ...        ...           ...   
3930   20.724169   15.941802   10.689522 -23.076279 -32.946592     42.772550   
3931   31.217812   37.470711   35.944079  20.029908  -4.074200   -120.340583   
3932   22.335940   17.800092   15.002296 -20.307399 -15.717870    -22.600279   
3933   16.127509   19.467663   19.082734  20.710909  -1.977275   -109.547023   
3934   27.214603   21.382337   20.304794 -21.430647  -5.039407    -76.485045   
3935   30.145448   24.860376   24.226530 -17.531908  -2.549624    -85.457236   
3936   36.156551   34.442185   30.118402  -4.741508 -12.553740    164.762581   
3937   40.073225   44.157307   28.200753  10.191548 -36.135704   -454.565404   
3938   25.800946   22.210817   18.462537 -13.914720 -16.875921     21.281067   
3939   56.025248   44.785867   36.813963 -20.061280 -17.800044    -11.271643   
3940   21.721465   16.580673   17.066158 -23.666875   2.928013   -112.371776   
3941  126.042248  104.034079  125.245191 -17.460946  20.388620   -216.766980   
3942   29.973334   24.949141   16.146185 -16.762210 -35.283605    110.494953   
3943  107.575315  101.958098   76.669257  -5.221660 -24.803170    375.005481   
3944   24.792904   26.085561   26.976141   5.213821   3.414073    -34.518798   
3945   29.213314   24.932513   21.345969 -14.653597 -14.385006     -1.832930   
3946   25.262395   24.299451    5.572292  -3.811766 -77.068238   1921.851267   
3947   21.198833   10.842775    4.900851 -48.852021 -54.800770     12.177078   
3948   45.819434   56.501595   66.138568  23.313603  17.056107    -26.840535   
3949   22.805006   16.118201   13.746766 -29.321656 -14.712774    -49.822840   
3950   26.982351   26.434291   14.190090  -2.031179 -46.319384   2180.418856   
3951   23.402449   21.028677   18.554475 -10.143262 -11.765848     15.996685   
3952   22.456039   15.978894   15.625565 -28.843666  -2.211222    -92.333770   
3953   19.181484   15.020811   14.010314 -21.691089  -6.727314    -68.985819   
3954   23.906623   20.085022   15.845863 -15.985531 -21.106072     32.032347   
3955   24.307415   19.032445   13.309898 -21.701075 -30.067320     38.552214   
3956   41.598373   41.169011   23.564185  -1.032162 -42.762323   4042.987059   
3957  246.589896   16.824434   11.003777 -93.177160 -34.596450    -62.870246   
3958   29.894166   29.932545   24.548939   0.128381 -17.985793 -14109.652460   
3959   25.683951   22.443694   12.041074 -12.615881 -46.349857    267.392937   

      2010rank  105rank  absrank  
0           89       57       99  
1           33       26       75  
2           71       42       33  
3            2       92       10  
4           80        9       31  
5           36       63        6  
6           53       33       62  
7           34        6       57  
8           95       93       74  
9            9       75       11  
10          47       81       29  
11           7       20       80  
12          59       87       37  
13          31       46       86  
14          77       95       53  
15          15       83       16  
16           1       89        8  
17          85       49        5  
18          24       82       19  
19          62       38       56  
20          67       73       40  
21          92        2       34  
22          78       25       30  
23          39        4       49  
24          23       88       22  
25          64       62       25  
26          83       60       91  
27          61       31       52  
28          49       96       35  
29          72       72       50  
...        ...      ...      ...  
3930        26       26       74  
3931        66       91       22  
3932        53       34       53  
3933        71       92       26  
3934        64       32       39  
3935        67       39       37  
3936        59       67       85  
3937        19       85        7  
3938        52       50       69  
3939        51       35       57  
3940        81       24       25  
3941        93       40       15  
3942        21       42       81  
3943        37       66       89  
3944        83       81       48  
3945        57       49       60  
3946         1       71       97  
3947         4        4       66  
3948        90       94       50  
3949        56       19       47  
3950         8       74       98  
3951        60       58       68  
3952        69       20       35  
3953        63       30       41  
3954        42       45       71  
3955        30       29       72  
3956        10       75       99  
3957        23        1       44  
3958        50       76        1  
3959         7       54       88  

[3960 rows x 14 columns]
```

Comment: If you're referring to the `.....` this is just pandas truncating your output

Comment: Hey EdChum thanks for the reply not sure why it would truncate my data I thought it would just pump out what's in the dataframe as default. Did I mess up somehow and tell it to truncate? This is a fresh install

Comment: The point being it truncates the output, not the data, the data is still there, it would be pretty pointless to use a data structure that limited the number of rows to 200

Comment: gotcha and thanks for the guidance EdChum I have the answer thanks to the very splendid @andyhaden

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default is to truncate, if you have several million rows you don't want it to crash your machine/pipe out for ages. This is configurable however:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: pd.options.display.max_rows
Out[2]: 15

In [3]: pd.options.display.max_rows = 9999

In [4]: pd.options.display.max_rows
Out[4]: 9999
```

Now when your print your DataFrame it will print the entire frame (assuming it's fewer than 9999 rows). Increase the number at your own risk... :)

See the [options docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).

Comment: I usually also increase pd.options.display.width = 300 (or something) so each row appears on the same line in my terminal.

Comment: Hey Andy first of all thank you for your excellent guidance AND I apologise for not being able to find this myself. I will try harder next time. Thank you so much for not giving me the verbal pummeling I so richly deserve...

Comment: @theakson no need to apologize, this question will make it all the easier for the next person looking. :)